# bcrypt.compare returns false for correct password

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

The title is self-explaining. I've checked everything, password sent to server for registration and password sent to server for authentication are the same. I've even tried using `bcrypt.compare` right after hashing for registration and it returned `true`. But every time I use `bcrypt.compare` for authentication it returns `false`. And yes, I've checked and I've always got the right account.

```
app.post('/api/accounts/register', function(req, res, next) {
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
        let newAccount = Account.model({
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hash,
            gender: req.body.gender,
            address: req.body.address,
            phone: req.body.phone
        });

        newAccount.save(err => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500);
            }
            res.json({
                account: getCleanUser(newAccount),
                token: generateToken(newAccount)
            });
        });
    })
});

app.post('/api/login', function(req, res, next) {
    Account.model.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
        .exec((err, account) => {
            console.log(account);
            if (err) return res.status(500);
            if (!account) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    error: true
                });
            }
            bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, account.password, (err, valid) => {
                if (!valid) {
                    return res.status(404).json({
                        error: true
                    });
                }
                let token = generateToken(account);
                res.json({
                    account: getCleanUser(account),
                    token: token
                });
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that `req.body.password`contains the value? Can you share the library that you're using for crypt?

Comment: Yes, req.body.password always has a value. The one I'm using is this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

Comment: Are you also sure that when registering the user the password is provided and is the same? You can do a dummy check by creatin g a function that will hash the value and check the hash afterwards

Comment: Yes, I tried `console.log` all the passwords in and out the server, and they were all the same

Comment: how do you know its returning false, and that its  not !account that returns res.status(404)?

Comment: @Stian I `console.log` the `account` and it's a valid object. However, `console.log(valid)` returned `false`

Comment: @RyanAleksander could it be that valid is false, because err is not null/undefined? Unlike when you get the account, you dont check err in the bcrypt.compare cb.

Comment: Have you check the err variable in bcrypt.compare function ?

Comment: I've just checked, `err` is undefined

Comment: I am facing similar issue. bcrypt.compare(oldPassword,user.hashpassword,(compareErr, same) returns random value :(